# importxml function in Google Sheets returns #N/A

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import a list of seller ratings on Amazon using a div id. This is the code:

`=importxml("https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&seller=A2JWZOZUWVCPDC", "//[@id='feedback-content']")`

An  #N/A is returned. I confirmed that the content is not created by Javascript. I'd appreciate any guidance.

---

**EDIT**

The solution from @player0 works well on Amazon US, but on other Amazon marketplaces the 2nd column has errors.

On Amazon CA, only 3 out of 5 feedbacks appeared in the wrong row.

Amazon UK has the same issue. A seller response ("We shipped...") is included. It is unneeded, but would be nice in a 3rd column.

The image below displays the actual results on the left, and the expected results on the right.

[image: Valid XHTML]

CA formula in B4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.amazon.ca/sp?_encoding=UTF8&marketplaceID=A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2&seller=A1FLFF2FVHQO18&sshmPath="), 3000, 1), 
"where Col1 contains 'a-text-quote' and Col1 matches '.*</span>$'", 0), ">(.*)</"))
```

UK formula in B12:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.amazon.co.uk/sp?_encoding=UTF8&marketplaceID=A1F83G8C2ARO7P&seller=A10B9ILJZU6LK2"), 3000, 1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'a-text-quote' and Col1 matches '.*</span>$'", 0), ">(.*)</"))
```

I tried several other divs and ids for the `Col1 contains` and `Col1 matches` but always received errors. Any additional help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REPT("★", REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&seller=A2JWZOZUWVCPDC"), 3000, 1), 
 "where Col1 matches '.*a-icon a-icon-star a-star-\d+ feedback-stars.*'", 0), "\d+")))
```

[image]

---

### B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&seller=A2JWZOZUWVCPDC"), 3000, 1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'a-text-quote' and Col1 matches '.*</span>$'", 0), ">(.*)</"))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that, but I still had some testing left and wanted to leave it open in case I encountered issues. It turns out that issues do exits.

Comment: I edited the question to explain unexpected issues.